# Python - trying to Calculate the distance between Starting post code and Destination post code for each entry of my data. Issue with Country

Tags: python

I have the following table:

| Country | Starting Post Code | Destination post Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 99685 | 65039 |
| GB | AB15 | DD9 |

That I am trying to run the following query to return the road miles between the starting and end postcodes, but as I am learning Python I am struggling to get it to pass in the Country from the table below. I can use the commented-out code to pass either 'GB' or 'US' but I need to have this variable built in from the table.

```
import pandas as pd
import pgeocode
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\APP DEV\Python\\distance\\Road\\Address.xlsx",sheet_name=0)
#dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance('GB')
dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance(df['Country']).astype(str).to_list()
df["Distance"]=dist.query_postal_code(df['Starting Post Code'].astype(str).to_list(),df['Destination post Code'].astype(str).to_list())

print(df)
```

The issue is with the following line:

```
dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance(df['Country']).astype(str).to_list()
```

The error traceback I get is as follows:

```
> Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "c:\Users\kyddgorg\Desktop\APP
> DEV\Python\distance\Road\Distance.py", line 6, in <module>
>     dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance(df['Country']).astype(str).to_list()   File
> "C:\Users\kyddgorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pgeocode.py",
> line 333, in __init__
>     super().__init__(country)   File "C:\Users\kyddgorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pgeocode.py",
> line 193, in __init__
>     country = country.upper()   File "C:\Users\kyddgorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
> line 5575, in __getattr__
>     return object.__getattribute__(self, name) AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit messy. I'll help you with the edit if you would like.

Comment: Also, at first glance, pgeocode.GeoDistance(country:str,..) takes a str, you're giving it a list.

Comment: Don't forget to clearly state what you want from this code, in your case I'd think : "I want to calculate the distance between `Starting post code` and `Destination post code` for each entry of my data"

Comment: Apologies guys, I have made a few changes hopefully it is easier to follow what I am asking

Comment: Please consider reviewing your edit suggestions by accepting or rejecting them so as to not have a full edit queue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of modifying the column labels to unify their names, please make sure they match your data files.

```
import pgeocode
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\APP DEV\Python\\distance\\Road\\Address.xlsx",sheet_name=0)

## This is a dictionary that simulates the data
# data = {
#     "Country": ["US", "GB"],
#     "Starting post code": ["99685", "AB15"],
#     "Destination post code": ["65039", "DD9"],
# }
# df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=data)

df["Distance"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: pgeocode.GeoDistance(row["Country"]).query_postal_code(
        row["Starting post code"], row["Destination post code"]
    ),
    axis=1,
)

print(df)
```

I must warn you that using `apply` is quite inneficient and may scale badly if you have a millions of rows.

Comment: Thank you Imad, this worked perfectly. And thank you for the warning on the apply method, I will try to replicate the above for other queries going forward :)